# Google Apps Script passing parameter to google.script.run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can not pass parameter from Page.html file to google.script.run function

```
<input type="button" value="Load Norm"
onclick="google.script.run
      .loadNormFromSidebar('10A')" />
```

Then I am expecting to have 10A as parameter to my loadNormFromSidebar function:

```
function loadNormFromSidebar(normNr) {
  Logger.log(normNr);
  var jobNr = params.getDescriptionSheet().getRange(params.jobNrCell).getValue();
  normNr=jobNr+'-'+normNr;
  loadNormWithNr(normNr);
}
```

Any ideas why normNr is not passed from html to gs?
Log output file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found mistake. Above code is part of library Estimating. In local file I had

```
function loadNormFromSidebar() {
  Estimating.loadNormFrimSidebar()
}
```

where should be

```
function loadNormFromSidebar(normNr) {
  Estimating.loadNormFrimSidebar(normNr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem. In my test everything works as expected.

**Index.html**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button"
           value="Load Norm"
           onclick="google.script.run.loadNormFromSidebar('10A')" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function loadNormFromSidebar(normNr) {
  Logger.log(normNr);
  /*
  var jobNr = params.getDescriptionSheet().getRange(params.jobNrCell).getValue();
  normNr=jobNr+'-'+normNr;
  loadNormWithNr(normNr);
  */
}
```

**View -> Logs**

[image]

Have you created a new version of your application and published that version?

Comment: Found mistake. Explanation above. Thank for your help.